"Would have been" for speculation in the past
My Student's book recommend using the construction "would have been" to speculate about the past.
For example,

I'd imagine someone like Charles Darwin would have been a
naturalistic thinker.

I know that "would" have a variety of meanings. So I have looked it up in my grammar books (Murphy, English Grammar in Use; Swan, Practical English Usage), but I have found nothing about this particular meaning.
I have also searched in the Cambridge Dictionary https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would There is no information either.
The only information I have found on the topic is on this forum here "WOULD HAVE" OR "MUST HAVE" FOR A SPECULATION IN THE PAST
But unfortunately, it doesn't give much detail about this particular construction.
I'm confused.
As far as I understand, usually "would have..." is used in unreal conditional for unreal past. But this seems not to be the case. Although I really have a temptation to say:

I'd imagine someone like Charles Darwin would have been a
naturalistic thinker, but he wasn't.

I wonder if anyone could eventually expand on it.
Thank you so much in advance!

An unreal conditional sentence can express speculation. It is 'unreal' that Charles Darwin was a naturalistic thinker, given that we don't know that he was.

"I'd [I would] imagine that Darwin would have been..." The first would is Cambridge's definition used to express an opinion in a polite way without being forceful, the second would is used to refer to what is very likely.

The sentence you find tempting starts out saying one thing but ends up saying another. The “I'd imagine someone like Charles Darwin would have been a naturalistic thinker” can be paraphrased as “If I were compelled to make a guess, knowing what I do about Darwin and those like him, that guess would be that he was a naturalistic thinker.” But the concluding “but he wasn’t” expresses something that the speaker knows about Darwin. And if the speaker does indeed know Darwin wasn’t a naturalistic thinker, then the speaker would not imagine that he was one.
